# Discord.py recognizing on_message client event, but IF statements not responding

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, discord, discord.py

I am working on a Discord bot and in this case want the bot to roll a 6 sided die when any user gives the "roll" command. See code below. Oddly enough this was working just fine, but now the `print(worked)` triggers and the `if p_message` statements do nothing. I get no errors, it just doesn't work.

```
import discord
import random

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  p_message = message
  print("worked")

  if p_message == "roll":
    return str(random.randint(1, 6))

client.run('***') #my token
```

I have tried ensuring that `message` is a `str` but it makes no difference. Again, this code worked previously (at 1am when I was probably too tired to be writing code) and throws no error. It just doesn't respond to the command at all in discord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import discord
import random

# change .all to .default
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # use message.content
    if message.content == "roll":
        # send message to the channel that someone types "roll"
        await message.channel.send(random.randint(1, 6))


client.run('***')  # my token
```

Comment: Just to clarify what's done here, `message.content` is used instead of `message` because `message` is not a string, it's a discord message. The reason the conditional never triggered is because it never gets set to true. Also `await message.channel.send(random.randint(1, 6))` sends it back. You may need to convert `random.randint(1,6)` to a string though, I would imagine .send accepts strings, but maybe it just converts instead of throwing an error.

Comment: God bless you, @It_is_Chris! It looks like the lack of an `await` command was preventing this code from triggering AND blocking later code as well. This worked! Thanks!

Comment: @BrockBrown thank you for adding the explanation. I did test sending `message.channel.send(random.randint(1, 6))` and it works without needing to be converted to a string